Kaldi Application fails to load as a debian systemd service when the memory requirement is high
I have an C++ application that loads a Kaldi ASR model. If the model is small, the application is able to load the model and run in command line as well as a systemd service under Debian 12.
However, when I am loading a bigger Kaldi ASR model, service fails to load, but it runs fine from command line. I am really scratching my head here, what is the limitation being applied here while running as service. There is no memory limit specified in the service file.
Following is the service file:
[Unit]
Description=kaldiasr-english
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target local-fs.target network.target network-online.target

[Service]
; service
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/log/kaldiasr-english.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=true
; blank ExecStart= line flushes the list

Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib"
ExecStart=kaldiasr 8010 60 English vosk-model-en-us-0.22
TimeoutSec=45s
Restart=on-failure
; exec
WorkingDirectory=/home/test
User=test
Group=test
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitNOFILE=100000
LimitNPROC=60000
;LimitSTACK=240
LimitRTPRIO=infinity
LimitRTTIME=7000000
IOSchedulingClass=realtime
IOSchedulingPriority=2
CPUSchedulingPolicy=rr
CPUSchedulingPriority=89
UMask=0007

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The log from Kaldi is as follows:
Apr 27 22:03:00 staging-svr2 kaldiasr[1399961]: LOG (VoskAPI:ReadDataFiles():model.cc:308) Loading winfo vosk-model-en-us-0.22/graph/phones/word_boundary.int
Apr 27 22:03:00 staging-svr2 kaldiasr[1399961]: LOG (VoskAPI:ReadDataFiles():model.cc:315) Loading subtract G.fst model from vosk-model-en-us-0.22/rescore/G.fst
Apr 27 22:03:03 staging-svr2 kaldiasr[1399961]: LOG (VoskAPI:ReadDataFiles():model.cc:317) Loading CARPA model from vosk-model-en-us-0.22/rescore/G.carpa
Apr 27 22:03:03 staging-svr2 kaldiasr[1399961]: LOG (VoskAPI:ReadDataFiles():model.cc:323) Loading RNNLM model from vosk-model-en-us-0.22/rnnlm/final.raw
Apr 27 22:03:07 staging-svr2 systemd[1]: kaldiasr-english.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Apr 27 22:03:07 staging-svr2 systemd[1]: kaldiasr-english.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 27 22:03:07 staging-svr2 systemd[1]: kaldiasr-english.service: Consumed 8.088s CPU time.
Apr 27 22:03:07 staging-svr2 systemd[1]: kaldiasr-english.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Apr 27 22:03:07 staging-svr2 systemd[1]: Stopped kaldiasr-english.service - asr-english.
Apr 27 22:03:07 staging-svr2 systemd[1]: kaldiasr-english.service: Consumed 8.088s CPU time.
Apr 27 22:03:07 staging-svr2 systemd[1]: Started kaldiasr-english.service - asr-english.

